# (Auto)paying for chametz on Pesach

Tags: halacha, transactions, chametz-leaven, contemporary-halacha, ownership

My understanding is that one only acquires movable objects, such as food items, by moving them physically (e.g. lifting or pulling them; or by acquiring them along with land; or via *chalipin* exchange, which doesn't work with money - see e.g. [Bava Batra 149a](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Batra.149a.5?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi&with=Commentary&lang2=en)). Accordingly, would there be any issue with paying/autopaying for chametz on/before Pesach if it would definitely arrive after Pesach - for example if one has a subscription to a merchant, such as Amazon, that would charge on Pesach though the delivery would only arrive after Pesach?  Could there be an issue, for example, of *dina d'malchuta* (the law of the land) if the civil law is that the ownership is from time of payment/shipment?

Comment: Where is your initial understanding from?

Comment: https://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/876238/rabbi-aryeh-lebowitz/ten-minute-halacha-amazon-subscribe-and-save-over-pesach/